# Docker - no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm receiving an error from docker when I run my docker file. It's saying the  /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/xxxx: no such file or directory when I run Docker build .

I have tried numerous ways to remove containers and images so I'm pretty much stock on this one.

Any

The Docker file is:

```
FROM node:6

RUN git clone https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack.git

WORKDIR angular2-webpack

RUN sed -i.bak 's/--port 8080/--host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080/'
package.json RUN npm i

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

The complete console output is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon
9.728 kB
Step 1 : FROM node:6
6: Pulling from library/node
6a5a5368e0c2: Already exists
7b9457ec39de: Already exists
ff18e19c2db4: Already exists
6a3d69edbe90: Already exists
0ce4b037e17f: Already exists
82252a100d5a: Already exists
Digest:
sha256:db245bde5445eb122d8dc090ba98539a9ef7f56c0ea981ade643695af0d8eaf0
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:6
---> 9873603dc506 Step 2 :
RUN git clone https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack.git open
/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/9319fd93cb6d6718243ff2e65ce5d2aa6122a1bb9211aa9f8e88d85c298727e5:
no such file or directory User:docker-test
```

> Edit

The issue was resolved thanks to @BMitchs' recommendation:

1. rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
2. Uninstall Docker completely
3. re install docker

Comment: You may need to specify the working directory before running git clone, or else your cloning into whatever the original node image specified as its working directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With that sort of corruption, I'd give a full docker wipe a try, `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*`. Before doing that, backup any data (volumes), then shutdown docker, and you'll need to pull or rebuild all your images again. If there are still problems with aufs, try changing the filesystem driver, e.g. changing to `dockerd -s overlay2` in your service startup.

It doesn't hurt to check for common issues, like running out of disk space or old version of the application, first.

Comment: thank you, removing the folder worked. I will update the question to include the steps I did to resolve the issue.

Comment: Where is the /var/lib file located on windows?

Comment: @FordO. I don't have any Windows machines. The question above appears to be for a Linux install. If you have a different question, please use the ask question link.

Answer (score 2):

try building the image again on a clean machine or using the --no-cache flag, this seems like a caching issue.

Also - In my company, we clone the code into the machine building the image, and then copy the code into the container. In my opinion - it's a better solution, but I think it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I agree with cloning the code to the host machine and `COPY` it to the container. That way you can control which version/revision is actually used. In OPs case, the container can end up with different version depending on the day the container is built.

Comment: I tried to use the --no-cache flag but got the same error

Answer (score 2):

The data files used by Docker are corrupted. You can execute the following command:

1- If they exist, delete contain and image

```
docker rm CONTAINER ID
docker rmi IMAGE ID
```

2- Stop the Docker service (Ubuntu)

```
service docker stop
```

3- Start the Docker service (Ubuntu)

```
service docker start
```

4- Check Docker service status (Ubuntu)

```
service docker status
```

Comment: This solution works. I deleted my `/var/lib/docker` folder and had this error. The solution works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Windows + shell scripts

I am writing this answer here partially for myself when I arrive to the same issue in a few months again.

If you run docker on **windows** and get such errors about files not being found located at **shell script** entrypoints (or generally), make sure the scripts do not have `CRLF` line endings. Otherwise, they just behave weirdly and it's hell to try to debug.

Answer (score -1):

```
docker system prune -af
```

worked for me

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.