# COPY of existing file in Dockerfile fails mysteriously

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am currently experiencing very strange behaviour while trying to rebuild some docker containers. The build fails at the following line:

```
COPY ./startup.sh /
```

where I get the following error:

```
Step 15 : COPY ./startup.sh /
stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/03a7dbf0115dabea5d4cb0ee7ebc84fe79254066089e50e8a7fb55c0c31d8c8d/startup.sh: no such file or directory
```

The file is available in the current directory, also no dockerignore file is present:

```
$ ls -al
insgesamt 65032
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Okt 18 14:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 user user 4096 Okt 17 17:33 ..
-rwxr--r--  1 user user 89 Okt 18 15:12 build
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user 17879 Mär  4  2016 catalina.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 3531 Okt 18 15:26 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 3470 Aug  2 14:13 Dockerfile.org
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 44043922 Jul  4 09:40 deploy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 0 Okt 18 14:50 foo
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 309780 Mär  2  2016 jolokia.war
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 111731 Jul 13 13:13 keyspace_3x.cql
-rwxr--r--  1 user user 3551 Jul  5 14:06 startup.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 17227683 Mai 10 10:32 statusLogging.war
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user 84 Jul 13 12:49 tools
-rwx------  1 user user 4839500 Jul 13 13:33 tools-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

There are two points i find interesting:

- It looks like it hast something to do with the destination. When I modify the COPY instruction to something like this: `COPY ./startup.sh /foo.sh` it complains about `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/.../foo.sh` not being there.
- Copying stuff into other directorys than / works, like in the following instructions:

  COPY ./tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
  COPY ./*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

The really strange thing here is that the build worked a few weeks ago, but now it fails besides no changes to the files and folders.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: full dockerfile:

```
FROM java:7-jre

MAINTAINER user


ENV http_proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8111
ENV https_proxy https://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8111



ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

# see https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/KEYS
#RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys \
#       05AB33110949707C93A279E3D3EFE6B686867BA6 \
#       07E48665A34DCAFAE522E5E6266191C37C037D42 \
#       47309207D818FFD8DCD3F83F1931D684307A10A5 \
#       541FBE7D8F78B25E055DDEE13C370389288584E7 \
#       61B832AC2F1C5A90F0F9B00A1C506407564C17A3 \
#       79F7026C690BAA50B92CD8B66A3AD3F4F22C4FED \
#       80FF76D88A969FE46108558A80B953A041E49465 \
#       8B39757B1D8A994DF2433ED58B3A601F08C975E5 \
#       A27677289986DB50844682F8ACB77FC2E86E29AC \
#       A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 \
#       B3F49CD3B9BD2996DA90F817ED3873F5D3262722 \
#       DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243 \
#       F3A04C595DB5B6A5F1ECA43E3B7BBB100D811BBE \
#       F7DA48BB64BCB84ECBA7EE6935CD23C10D498E23

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 6
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 6.0.45
ENV TOMCAT_TGZ_URL http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN set -x \
        && curl -fSL "$TOMCAT_TGZ_URL" -o tomcat.tar.gz \
        && curl -fSL "$TOMCAT_TGZ_URL.asc" -o tomcat.tar.gz.asc \
        && tar -xvf tomcat.tar.gz --strip-components=1 \
        && rm bin/*.bat \
        && rm tomcat.tar.gz* \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get -y install mc \
        && apt-get -y install openssh-server \
        && apt-get install -yq gcc make openssl libssl-dev libapr1 libapr1-dev openjdk-7-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        && tar zxf /usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz -C /tmp \
        && cd /tmp/tomcat-native*-src/jni/native/ \
        && ./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ --with-ssl=yes --libdir=/usr/lib/jni \
        && make \
        && make install \
        && apt-get purge -y openjdk-7-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" gcc make libssl-dev libapr1-dev \
        && apt-get -y autoremove \
        && rm -rf /tmp/tomcat-native* \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  \
        && rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs \
        && rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples \
        && rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager \
        && rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager \
        && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd \
        && echo "session optional pam_umask.so umask=0002" >> /etc/pam.d/sshd \
        && sed -r -i "s/(^Subsystem.*)/#\1/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "#Custom" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "Match Group sftp-user" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "   ChrootDirectory /data/" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && echo "   ForceCommand internal-sftp" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        && groupadd sftp-user \
        && useradd -g sftp-user sftp-user 

RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

COPY ./startup.sh /
COPY ./tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY ./*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY ./catalina.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 7199

RUN rmdir /usr/local/tomcat/logs \
    && ln -s /arkadon/logs /usr/local/tomcat/logs \
    && ln -s /arkadon/logs /var/log/tomcat6

COPY ./tools* /usr/local/bin/
COPY keyspace* /

CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: it might help to see the Dockerfile.

Comment: @user2915097 added.

Comment: does the `COPY keyspace* /` work?

Comment: @user2915097 that doesn't work either, but the COPYs inbetween work. I think it has something to do with the target location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938612/docker-no-such-file-or-directory/39943171#39943171

Comment: do you have a .dockerignore in your build directory? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file

Comment: @user2915097 No .dockerignore file is present.

Comment: Interestingly, what works is COPYing the files to a different directory in the container and then calling RUN mv /someotherdir/startup.sh /

Comment: Can you try  `docker build --no-cache`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try your Dockerfile building in another machine or VM. Your error looks like a corruption in aufs layers. If it succeed on another machine, you need to clean docker. This answer talks about resetting docker: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938612/docker-no-such-file-or-directory/39943171#39943171)

Regards

Comment: I tested the Dockerfile on another machine where it worked flawlessly. So it looks like my docker installation is somehow corrput. I will try to clean my installation as described in your link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my docker build error,

```
COPY failed: stat /<**path**> :no such file or directory
```

I got it around by restarting docker service.

```
sudo service docker restart
```