# IntelliJ docker deployment ADD: no such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, dockerfile

I installed the docker integration plugin for IntelliJ to deploy instantly a project.
Currenty I'm working on a project with gradle. There the strucure looks like:

```
project  
|- build/
|-- docker/
|--- Dockerfile
|--- target/
|---- myApp.jar
|- docker/
|-- Dockerfile
|- src/
|-- de.myApp/
|--- SOURCECODE
|- build.gradle
|- gradlew
```

In my *Dockerfile* I add the `.jar` with:
`ADD target/data_sample_set_structure_consumer-0.0.0.jar app.jar`

The deployment configuration uses `Deployment: docker/Dockerfile`.

When I click on *start*, I get the following error message:

```
Step 3/4 : ADD target/data_sample_set_structure_consumer-0.0.0.jar app.jar

Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=<null>,message=ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder981429297/target/data_sample_set_structure_consumer-0.0.0.jar: no such file or directory]
Failed to deploy '<unknown>  Dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile': ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder981429297/target/data_sample_set_structure_consumer-0.0.0.jar: no such file or directory
```

But if I build the *Dockerfile* with `./gradlew buildDocker` everything is fine.

PS:
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938612/docker-no-such-file-or-directory) without effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ Docker integration assumes that the context folder for the docker build is always the parent folder of the Dockerfile.

In your case it is actually `<project-root>/docker` folder (as specified in `Deployment: docker/Dockerfile`). And what you actually want is to use the file copied by the maven build into `<project-root>/build/docker`

In IntelliJ 2017.2 there are no ways to choose the docker file from the build folder, so for 2017.2 the only workaround is to configure the build to additionally copy the target folder somewhere under the `<project-root>/docker`

For IDEA 2017.3 Docker run configuration allows to choose any docker file inside and outside of the project, so you should be able to choose the location under the build folder. Please check the IDEA 2017.3 [public preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) and the updated  docker [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7724-docker-integration/update/39928)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing on this question like me.
Things have changed since the last answer.

You can now specify the context folder for the IntelliJ Docker integration.
You can do so by going here: `Run > Edit Configurations > Select your docker run/debug config` and specify the `Context folder`