# No such file or directory, when building scala docker image

Tags: docker

I have auto generated the following docker file with sbt for my scala project:

```
FROM robsonoduarte/8-jre-alpine-bash:latest
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD opt /opt
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
EXPOSE 6999
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/app"]
CMD []
```

Yet when I run `build . -t app` I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  166.2MB
Step 1/7 : FROM robsonoduarte/8-jre-alpine-bash:latest
 ---> 9bbc00a23a9b
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /opt/docker
Removing intermediate container 817f86d4a46e
 ---> b648d213f308
Step 3/7 : ADD opt /opt
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder679116314/opt: no such file or directory
```

I have tried to reinstall docker as suggested in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938612/docker-no-such-file-or-directory), but that did not help. I am also using windows, and I cannot find the /var/lib folder.

Comment: what are you trying to do in step 3 'ADD opt /opt' is opt present on your local system?

Comment: As a comment, `COPY` is the recommended way to copy files from localhost to Docker container, see [Best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). `ADD` will decompress a compressed files on your Docker image, with the risk of spraying it.

Comment: OP uses generated dockerfiles through https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker so I suppose you could post your recommendation there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ADD command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) copies files from `<src>` to `<dest>`. In your case, Docker expects a folder called 'opt' from the location where you run `build . -t app`. Does such a folder exist?

Comment: No it doesn't, but there is `./stage/opt` so I will try to run the docker command from `./stage` folder.

Comment: Alternatively, you could change the dockerfile to `ADD ./stage/opt /opt`

Comment: Okay, so that was exactly the problem. I have run the docker command from `app/target/docker` instead of `app/target/docker/stage`.